# How to use pivot to select and flatten table?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm trying to select from a table that essentially is a hierarchy of groups and fields in each group. Each row has a group id column and I'm trying to flatten it into rows of each group id and their fields.

For example
`group id |  field1`  
   `1     |     a`    
   `1     |     b`    
   `1     |     a`    
   `1     |     b`    
   `2     |     c`    
   `2     |     d`    
   `2     |     c`    
   `2     |     d`    
   `3     |     e`    
   `3     |     f`    
   `3     |     g`    
   `3     |     e`    
   `3     |     f`    
   `3     |     g`    
   `4     |     h`

It is guaranteed that a group will map to the same fields values so group 1 will always have the same number of rows with field 'a' as with field 'b'.

The target is this:

`group id   |  field1  |   field2   |   field 3`   
      `1       |     a    |      b     |     null`    
      `2       |     c    |      d     |     null`    
      `3       |     e    |      f     |      g`      
      `4       |     h    |    null    |     null`

I have been playing with over (order by group id) but I haven't made any progress with that or pivots either.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use pivot.  I would use conditional aggregation and `dense_rank()`:

```
select group_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then field1 end) as field1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then field1 end) as field2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then field1 end) as field3
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by group_id order by field1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by group_id
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. There is no max number of fields though, edge cases could have 50+, is there a possibility of handling it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will solve your problem. If you are generating any report then you can use LISTAGG function.

```
select listagg( field_1 , ',') within group (order by group_id)
from (
select distinct group_id, field_1 from table
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work as it clusters the result into a single cell and loses the mapping of group ids to corresponding field names